# Why is this example not antisymmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

R = {(a,a),(a,b),(b,a),(b,b),(b,c),(c,b),(c,c)}

I know that to be anti-symmetric aRb and bRa, which this example has, but this example also means that a does not equal b (which anti-symmetry needs to be true). How, in this example, does a not equal b even though it has aRb and bRa.

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R36F8CWAi2k&list=PLDDGPdw7e6Ag1EIznZ-m-qXu4XX3A0cIz&index=50) video tells me that aRb and bRa means a=b. But I also heard that antisymmetry needs there to be no edges (on a directed graph) going both ways (in other words, one-way) as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/225808/is-my-understanding-of-antisymmetric-and-symmetric-relations-correct).

As you may have already worked out, I am very confused, and I just hope my question hasn't confused you. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  You seem confused between symmetric and anti-symmetric.  To be *symmetric*, aRb and bRa.  To be anti-symmetric, aRb and *not* bRa unless a=b.

Comment: I know I am sounding silly, but how do I know when a=b? And thanks for the help.

Comment: Antisymmetric that if $aRb$ and $bRa$ then $a=b$.  That's why your $R$ is not antisymmetric.  $\leq$ on the real numbers is an example of an antisymmetric relation.

Comment: Forgot my other comment, I completely get it now. It is just one of those brain malfunctions. Seriously, thank you for clearing this up. Even though it wasn't much you said, it was in my mind. It has clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relation is said to be symmetric when aRb if and only if bRa.

A relation is said to be anti-symmetric when aRb and bRa implies a=b.

Your relation is symmetric because it has (a,b) and (b,a) and (b,c) and (c,b).

Your relation is not anti-symmetric because it has (a,b) and (b,a) but a$\ne$b

(and (b,c) and (c,b) but b$\ne$c).

Another example of an anti-symmetric relation, besides the one given in the comments,

is "divides" for natural numbers, because, if a divides b, and b divides a, then a=b.